# How to correctly reference a nuget package so it won't hard code a path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

What is the best way to reference a libarary downloaded using nuget?

When I go to references and then find the path to the library inside of the packages folder, it seems to include my TFS branch path in the reference path.

How do I get it to reference the dll in a more generic way?

I don't see the "installed packages" options either:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to reference a libarary downloaded using nuget?

You should set that nuget package to a local feed, then manage it with nuget.

**Detail steps:**

**Create local feed:**

1. Go to `Tools`->`Options`->`NuGet Package Manager`->`Package Sources`, click the green plus button, then add a available package source and configure the `Name` of package source and `Source`:

   [image]
2. Add the downloaded package to the load feed, which you set in the `Source` of package source in the first step.

**Manage package with nuget:**

Right click on the References, select `Manage NuGet packages...`, select local feed source on the opened NuGet Package Manager window, find the downloaded package, then you can add it by clicking Install button:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the package directly.  Add the package to the project using Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.